# How to fetch data based on id condition in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, foreign-keys

I am trying to fetch data based on case_id which is from cases table and I fk (case_id) in my sockets table but I am getting empty array in my response:

Here is my controller:

```
public function index($case_id)
    {
        $id = kase::find($case_id);

        $data = DB::table('sockets')->where('case_id',$id)->get();
        return $data;
    }
```

My route:

```
 Route::get('/case-log/{id}', 'CaseLogController@index');
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting null for kase::find($case_id) because laravel assumes the primary key and index is named 'id'. To override this setting on your `kase` model, please set it as follows. You can also build your relationship to your `socket` model as follows:

```
class kase extends Model
{
    ...
    protected $primaryKey = 'case_id';
    ...
    
    
    public function sockets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(socket::class, 'case_id');
    }
}
```

Also you need to have your controller method parameters match your route parameters. So:

```
public function index($id)
{
    $case = kase::with('sockets')->find($id);
   
    return $case->sockets;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The slug name in your route should match the parameter name in your `index` method so you have to change one of these

```
Route::get('/case-log/{case_id}', 'CaseLogController@index');
```

and

```
public function index($case_id)
{
    $id = kase::find($case_id);

    $data = DB::table('sockets')->where('case_id',$id)->get();
    return $data;
}
```